# Htaccess - Combining underscore to hyphen and uppercase to lowercase 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, httpd.conf

At the moment I'm using an underscore the hyphen 301 on my site, this is working well but I also want to convert all links to lowercase and add an uppercase to lower case rewrite.

I can do this but with the current method it would do the following which I don't think would be very good for SEO:

1. Original URL
2. 301
3. Hyphen Replaced
4. 301
5. Hyphen Lowercase URL

How can I combine the following rewrites into one query so that urls with either underscores or uppercase are converted to hyphens and lowercase via a 301?

**Underscore to Hyphens rewrite**

```
RewriteRule ^post/([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*)$ /posts/new-category-1/$1-$2 [L,NE]
RewriteRule ^post/([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /posts/new-category-1/$1-$2 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^forum/([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*)$ /forums/new-category-1/$1-$2 [L,NE]
RewriteRule ^forum/([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /forums/new-category-1/$1-$2 [L,NE,R=301]
```

**Uppercase to Lowercase rewrite**

*httpd.conf*

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

*.htaccess*

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*
RewriteRule ^ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid multiple `301` by having rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(post|forum)/([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*)$ /$1/$2-$3 [L,NE]

# if there is any upper case letter then do both lowercase conversion AND
# underscore to hyphen replacement
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(post|forum)/([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /${lc:$1}/${lc:$2}-${lc:$3} [L,NE,R=301]

# otherwise regular underscore to hyphen replacement
RewriteRule ^(post|forum)/([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1/$2-$3 [L,NE,R=301]

# and regular lower case conversion
RewriteRule ^(post|forum)/[^A-Z]*[A-Z] ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: At the moment this allows uppercase letters if there isn't an underscore?

Comment: It seems to redirect `/profiles/Person` to `/profiles/person`? The last line seems to run on any URL and not just the matched one?

Comment: Would it be possible to only do the lowercase on the `(post|forum)` or not on `/profiles/name`?

Comment: I need to very slightly tweak this rule so that `http://domain.com/forum/this_iS_a_POST_1/` becomes `http://domain.com/forums/category-1/this-is-a-post-1/`, have it mostly working but it appends multiple of the first part on the end?

Comment: Just came online so missed your chat. I don't have any rule adding `/category-1/` in the URI. Looks like your other rules are conflicting. Make sure you keep other rules after above shown rules in your .htaccess and test in a new browser. Also if it doesn't resolve please open a new question as it is not east to understand a complex problems from comments section.

Comment: @Dan: There is no directive here that won't work in Apache 2.4. Besides I myself have Apache 2.4 where I do all the testing before posting an answer. What might have changed is some Apache config between old Apache and Apache 2.4 on your host.

Comment: Hmm if it does just the lowercase to uppercase it redirects to the DocumentRoot

Comment: Turned out to be I hadn't put `RewriteMap lc int:tolower` in the new vhost conf